# QTestLib results different from program output

Tags: qt, unicode, qstring, qtestlib

I have some simple code that reverses a QString.

```
const QString reverse_qstring(const QString& str_in)
{
    QString out;
    Q_FOREACH(const QChar c, str_in) {
        out.push_front(c);
    }
    return out;
}
```

When I input text from the command line with non-ASCII characters, things go as expected:

```
"¿como estás?" :  "?sátse omoc¿"
```

However, when I make the following unit test (Using QTestLib):

```
QCOMPARE(reverse_qstring(QString("¿como estás?")), QString("?sátse omoc¿"));
```

I get:

```
FAIL!  : program::test_qstring() Compared values are not the same
   Actual (reverse_qstring(QString("??como est??s?"))): ?s??tse omoc??
   Expected (QString("?s??tse omoc??")): ?s??tse omoc??
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can set the codec for Utf8: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtextcodec.html#setCodecForCStrings

Or you can use this instead: `QString::fromUtf8("?sátse omoc¿")`

Comment: Piece of cake! I wish unicode mappings weren't so numerous/non-obvious.